# How to delete an album?

Tags: facebook, batch-file, facebook-fql

I try in my application to delete an album, but there are no working methods.
I tried by using the url with parameters: the access token at the method, with batch request (but I don't know the syntax because on the net there are only GET example).

And sometimes some methods seems to work but I obtain this message:

> (#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API to remove content from Facebook (exceptions being posts and comments made by an app, which the app itself can delete)

Comment: I've would added likes to here too, since "unlike" is done by issuing DELETE to `like` connection of objects. Oh, and page-tabs ;)

Comment: Page tabs is more of a configuration thing (in my opinion) than content creation or removing, but yes, likes can be removed via the API too provided they're on photos, posts, etc (it doesnt include likes of pages)

Answer (score 0):

Graph API currently not providing ways to remove `album` or `photo`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your application cannot delete albums/photos.  Only white-listed apps can do this, and you will have to get the permissions approved by Facebook (good luck getting a hold of them).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a Photo that a Application has uploaded.

deleted = facebookClient.deleteObject(facebookObjectId); (Java Code)

This is a boolean that will return true when my app deletes the photo. 
But unfortunately im searching for album deletion, and that doesn't seem to still be possible at the moment. :(